# How to say "as" emphatically?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, idiom, particle, emphasis

Consider the sentence "Marcus spoke as a manager".
Imagine that Marcus was speaking at a company event, and he gave his speech as a manager, not as a coworker — as a representative of the company, not his private self.
To emphasize this aspect, one might say "Marcus spoke in the capacity (or role) of manager".
I am not sure if I master the English idiom perfectly, but I hope my point gets across.

Now, I would like to be able to add this emphasis in Latin, too.
The best starting point would be an apposition, I believe:

> *Marcus dux locutus est.*
>   Marcus spoke as a manager.

*Dux* might not be a good translation for "manager", but that is irrelevant.
But how to form a more emphatic version?
I imagine some of these might work:

> *Marcus in/e munere ducis locutus est.*
>   *Marcus in/ex officio ducis locutus est.*

I prefer classical Latin if attested examples are available.

Comment: "Marcus, **gubernator quidem,** quaestiones clamavit." Is that too understated?

Comment: @Hugh I didn't know you could use *quidem* that way. Sounds promising. If you have examples to demonstrate such use, I would much appreciate it as an answer. It might not be as strong as "in the capacity of", but it matches my intention quite well.

Comment: @Hugh, This strikes me as an odd usage of _quidem_. Maybe it's just because of all the Pliny the Younger that I've been reading lately, but if I saw _Marcus, gubernator quidem..._, my first thought would be something like, 'Marcus – true, he's (just) a manager – but....' It may finally be time for me to dive into that copy of Joseph Solodow's book, _The Latin particle quidem_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option (in addition to the several excellent ones in answers so far) is to use *(in) loco* + gen., as in the phrase *in loco parentis* "as a parent, in the position of a parent".

[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlocus) (part IID of the entry) give a number of examples of this usage, such as:

- “in uxoris loco habere,” Ter. Heaut. 1, 1, 52: "to consider as a wife"
- “in liberum loco esse,” Cic. de Or. 2, 49, 200: "to be in the position of sons"
- “hostium loco esse,” Liv. 2, 4, 7: "to be in the position of an enemy"

So you could say e.g. *Marcus ducis loco locutus est*.

Comment: All the answers are excellent, and I had great difficulties choosing the one to accept. This feels like the best fit for my idea, but only by a narrow margin; different answers have different strengths. **Many thanks to all who answered!**

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that simple word order would also do the trick here:

> *Marcus locutus est dux* [or *procurator* or whatever]*.*

Comment: A good suggestion. Caesar would have approved!

Comment: I like this best of all the answers.

Comment: Yes, the best. Latin is always better for a simple and direct structure.

Answer (score 6):

A common and classically attested way of saying "to perform the role of X" is ***munere X fungi***, where "X" is an adjective or genitive noun. Here is an example:

> **fungar enim iam interpretis munere**, ne quis me putet fingere. (Cicero, *Tusculanae Disputationes*, 3.41)
>
> *I will now play the role of an interpreter, lest anyone accuse me of making things up.*

(Note that *vice X fungi* is also a common expression, with an important difference in meaning: it means to "assume the role of another" outside the normal course of things.)

My proposed translation of your sentence is thus:

> **Marcus, munere ducis fungens, locutus est.**

I did a quick corpus search and think a short *caveat* is in order: the present participle of *fungens* is not very common, probably because it is deponent. Here is one clear attested example though:

> Datames **militare munus fungens** primum, qualis esset, aperuit in bello, quod rex   aduersus Cadusios gessit. (Cornelius Nepos, *Vitae Dat.*, 1.2)

As a final note, I recommend *praepositus* or *praefectus* as better translations of "manager".

Comment: Gratias maximas tibi ago simulque gratulor, quod decem milia punctorum tulisti!

Comment: Excellent answer, though I would prefer *procurator* (in that sense see the meaning of *procuro*) as translation of "manager".

Answer (score 6):

I should like to extend @brianpck's answer by providing two further suggestions.

**1**. A neat way to express this is by using *qua*, as in these examples:

— *Ad hoc stipatum tribunal, atque etiam ex superiore basilicae parte qua feminae qua viri et audiendi — quod difficile — et — quod facile — visendi studio imminebant.* [Pl. Sec. ep.6, 33]

— *nam gladiatoribus qua dominus qua aduocati sibilis conscissi* [Cic. Att. 2, 19]

As in *Marcus qua procurator locutus est.*

**2**. You might also consider using *in statu*. The best-known example is *in statu pupillari*, widely used at Cambridge University, while old wills use a similar construction. *In* or *ex statu procuratoris* might serve.

Comment: I don't think either of these two examples shows a use of *qua* meaning "as": *qua ... qua* in both of them seems to mean "both ... and" or "now X, now Y". In any case, in *Marcus qua procuratore locutus est* surely it should be *procurator*, nominative.

Comment: @TKR Of course it should be procurator — that was careless of me. But I would defend the use of _qua_ : certainly, both... and... if you like (but you might equally say whether ... or). The point is that status is being shown, even if (as I concede) less exactly than it might be.

Comment: I think you're right that *qua* can mean "as" (it can even be used in that sense in English), though I don't actually know if this sense is found in classical Latin. But I don't think it means that in these examples: it doesn't seem right to translate "as women, as men" or "as the master, as the patrons" (or whatever the *advocati* are in this case). This usage looks more similar to things like *pars ... pars* or *partim ... partim* or *cum ... tum*, which isn't really what the OP is asking about.